# Why are Windows proxy lost when executing code via Ansible (remote WinRM)?

Tags: windows, powershell, internet-explorer, proxy, ansible

In automating Windows (2012R2 and 2016) builds, I found that even though I set a system-wide proxy via netsh, I still had to set the HKCU values for IE because some commands would not work without those values set. I would have to open IE and visit a site, any site, to initialize those settings, which was annoying.

I was able to find some PowerShell code that could "initialize" the IE proxy settings so I did not have to open IE and visit a site, shown below:

```
$Source=@"
[DllImport("wininet.dll")]
public static extern bool InternetSetOption(int hInternet, int dwOption, int lpBuffer, int dwBufferLength);
"@
$wininet = Add-Type -memberDefinition $Source -passthru -name InternetSettings
$wininet::InternetSetOption([IntPtr]::Zero, 95, [IntPtr]::Zero, 0)|out-null
$wininet::InternetSetOption([IntPtr]::Zero, 37, [IntPtr]::Zero, 0)|out-null
```

The above code is from https://vanderpaal.com.au/2016/09/30/live-proxy-setting-change/ (thanks!)

The above code works great when executed manually via RDP session. I set the IE proxy values correctly, I run the above code, and I can then do whatever I want - it all works. The commands that require the IE settings work fine.

I have been trying to run more code via remote WinRM using things like Ansible and SSM (in AWS). When I do, weird things happen.

Specifically, the IE proxy registry entries get deleted and reset back to defaults. So, the order of doing things via script is:

1. Write IE proxy values to the registry via script called by Ansible or SSM.
2. Run the initialize proxy code listed above.
3. IE values from #1 are gone...

I am at a loss as to why the registry values get deleted. I am 100% sure they get deleted - I can script a reg query before and after the initialize proxy commands - before the commands they exist, and after the commands they do not. This does not happen when I run the same scripts manually on the server in an RDP session - that is, the proxy command does NOT delete the entries.

I have replicated this in both Ansible and SSM, both of which use PowerShell and WinRM to run commands. The scripts reside on the actual server, and Ansible/SSM tell the system to execute the scripts.

I have verified that HKCU actually exists during Ansible execution of the scripts.

Because the IE values get deleted, the initialize command does me no good when the following commands that require the IE values execute. Those commands fail with errors like so:

PackageManagement\Install-Package : No match was found for the specified 
search criteria and module name ''

The commands I am running (which fail) are just install module commands, like so:

```
Install-Module -Name PSWindowsUpdate -Proxy http://proxy.foo.com:80 -Confirm:$false -Force
Install-Module -Name PowerShellGet -Proxy http://proxy.foo.com:80 -Confirm:$false -Force
```

Anyone know why the IE proxy registry values get deleted when I run the code above via Ansible or SSM? The proxy values in question are:

"HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnable" - this gets reset to 0

"HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyServer" - this gets deleted

"HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyOverride" - this gets deleted

Comment: `HKCU` settings are stored in the user profile and I suspect that this combined with remoting could be the issue. Have you tried setting `ProxySettingsPerUser = 0` and configuring proxy settings in `HKLM` ? Details: [Windows proxy settings explained](https://securelink.be/blog/windows-proxy-settings-explained/).

Comment: @beatcracker, thanks for that proxy link, it has good information. Unfortunately, even the HKLM systems are wiped by Jason's PowerShell code. I did the same before/after check, and sure enough, ProxyEnable is reset back to 0x0, ProxyServer is deleted, and ProxyOverride is deleted. Sigh...

Comment: I decided to try using psexec to run IE to do the proxy initialize (instead of Jason's PowerShell code) - that works works for the initialization, but also wipes out the settings. At this point, it appears that doing all this in an RDP session works perfectly. However, when doing this via WinRM (Ansible or AWS SSM), the proxy initialization wipes those settings. It makes sense that running IE would wipe the settings, since doing that and running the PS code do the exact same thing (initialize the wininet proxy). Anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

had the same problem. and found out that the damned ie wizard was the root cause. 
u have to add following key to registry before u can access ie components...:

```
    desc: "Remove IE 11 first run Wizard"
    path: "HKLM:\\Software\\Policies\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main"
    name: "DisableFirstRunCustomize"
    data: "1"
    type: "dword"
```